# WebSocket handshake error when connection to endpoint

Tags: websocket, twilio, sip, wss, twilio-functions

We were using Twilio Video for development of our system, I am able to use the system with my own laptop but working laptops have an error while trying to connect with Chrome browser.

I am getting below error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://endpoint.twilio.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing
```

The full error text is below:

```
twilio-video.js:20135 WebSocket connection to 'wss://endpoint.twilio.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing
connect @ twilio-video.js:20135
Transport @ twilio-video.js:20025
(anonymous) @ twilio-video.js:21181
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:07:49 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.transport | WebSocket connection error: {"isTrusted":true}
LoggerFactory.print @ twilio-video.js:14542
LoggerFactory.(anonymous function) @ twilio-video.js:14559
Logger.(anonymous function) @ twilio-video.js:14553
onError @ twilio-video.js:20315
ws.onerror @ twilio-video.js:20155
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:07:49 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.transport | WebSocket disconnected (code: 1006)
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:07:49 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.transport | WebSocket abrupt disconnection
LoggerFactory.print @ twilio-video.js:14542
LoggerFactory.(anonymous function) @ twilio-video.js:14559
Logger.(anonymous function) @ twilio-video.js:14553
onClose @ twilio-video.js:20204
ws.onclose @ twilio-video.js:20147
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:07:49 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.ua | transport wss://endpoint.twilio.com failed | connection state set to 2
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:07:49 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.ua | next connection attempt in 28 seconds
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:08:17 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.transport | connecting to WebSocket wss://endpoint.twilio.com
twilio-video.js:20135 WebSocket connection to 'wss://endpoint.twilio.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing
connect @ twilio-video.js:20135
Transport @ twilio-video.js:20025
(anonymous) @ twilio-video.js:21181
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:08:19 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.transport | WebSocket connection error: {"isTrusted":true}
LoggerFactory.print @ twilio-video.js:14542
LoggerFactory.(anonymous function) @ twilio-video.js:14559
Logger.(anonymous function) @ twilio-video.js:14553
onError @ twilio-video.js:20315
ws.onerror @ twilio-video.js:20155
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:08:19 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.transport | WebSocket disconnected (code: 1006)
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:08:19 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.transport | WebSocket abrupt disconnection
LoggerFactory.print @ twilio-video.js:14542
LoggerFactory.(anonymous function) @ twilio-video.js:14559
Logger.(anonymous function) @ twilio-video.js:14553
onClose @ twilio-video.js:20204
ws.onclose @ twilio-video.js:20147
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:08:19 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.ua | transport wss://endpoint.twilio.com failed | connection state set to 2
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:08:19 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.ua | next connection attempt in 30 seconds
twilio-video.js:14542 Tue Nov 28 2017 11:08:49 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time) | sip.transport | connecting to WebSocket wss://endpoint.twilio.com
```

We do not even understand what is the problem actually.

Comment: Do the laptops you're testing on where this doesn't work use a proxy?

Answer (score -1):

This error message means that you are trying to connect to a HTTP server and not to a WebSocket server.

Possible reasons:

1. The URI you are using is not correct (in the past i have seen correct twilio websocket URI in this format: wss://xxx.endpoint.twilio.com. In your example the xxx part is missing)
2. You are behind some HTTP proxy which doesn't support WebSocket